# Sharing same route with unauthenticated and authenticated users in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a route that where I'm using an auth middleware and it works great.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1','middleware' => ['auth:api']], function()
{
  Route::resource('user', 'v1\MyController');
});
```

The problem is that I would also like this route to be accessible to non-authenticated users as well. With the above, I get a 401 Unauthorized error and I can't return any content for unauthenticated users. So how can I authenticate this route (so it passes down the user data) while also allowing the route to proceed even if the user is NOT authenticated?

(I tried doing a conditional Auth check on the router page but it seems the user has gone through authentication yet so it always remains false.)

EDIT: I should also note that I'm using an API route with Password Grant & access tokens.

Comment: can you copy and past the content of the name middleware auth:api you will find it in karnal

Comment: This is the built-in Auth with Laravel 5.3 ('auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,)

Answer (score 8):

remove this route from current route group (which applies auth middleware).

then

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (array_key_exists('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', $_SERVER)) {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
}
```

then

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // Auth users
} else{ 
    //Guest users 
}
```

Comment: I just used your tips, It was working fine in localhost. And Then it shows unauthenticated in server. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing the same case.

since the auth middleware only checks for authenticated user, we can use client credentials for the non-authenticated user.

the client credentials have a separated middleware located in Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentails.

I have created a custom middleware to combine both middleware to allow either one is pass.

here is my custom middleware

```
namespace Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory;

class CheckClientCredentials
{
    /**
     * The Resource Server instance.
     *
     * @var ResourceServer
     */
    private $server;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  ResourceServer  $server
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceServer $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try{
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
           if (!in_array($scope,$psr->getAttribute('oauth_scopes'))) {
             throw new AuthenticationException;
           }
         }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernal.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.api' => \App\Http\Middleware\APIAuthenticate::class,
    ....
```

routes\api.php

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'API',
    'middleware' => 'auth.api:api',
], function(){
    ....
```

Comment: Where is your custom middleware "APIAuthrnticate"?

Comment: When using this middleware, I was unable to retrieve a user instance out of the user provider from the request (`request()->user()` returns null), so the grants on the JWT token returned by passport are not set correctly, specifically `oauth_user_id`.

Answer (score 2):

From within an unauthenticated (not assigned the auth:api middleware) route's handler method, try:

`Auth::guard("api")->user();`

If it's populated, then your unguarded route can treat the access as authenticated. If not, its a random user accessing the route, and can be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put those urls whome you want to allow for both guest users and authenticated users in auth middleware. Because auth middleware allow for only authenticated users.

To check for authenticated and unauthenticated user you can use following code in view

```
 @if (Auth::guest())
      //For guest users
 @else
      //for authenticated users
 @endif
```

Edited : In controller use

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // Auth users
} else{ 
  //Guest users 
}
```

Comment: In your view blade file, where you wrote your html code.

Comment: I'm not using views - I'm using API routes in Laravel 5.3. I updated my question to add this info.

Comment: When I do this (my route is using NO middleware), and I run `Auth::user()` or `Auth::check()` in the controller method, I invariably get null and false respectively even though the request is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

@Yves 's answer is nearly correct. But a small change,

Instead of array_key_exists, we need to check whether key value is not null. Because It always has that key but null value. SO, instead of controller construct check for authorization header like this.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) {
    $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
}
```

Then you can check for authenticated user like this:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
    // User is logged in and you can access using
    // auth()->user()
} else {
    // Unauthenticated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for sanctum use:

```
    if (Auth::guard('sanctum')->check()) {
        // user is logged in
        /** @var User $user */ $user = Auth::guard('sanctum')->user();
    } else {
        // user is not logged in (no auth or invalid token)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved mine in another way.
Remove the route from the middleware group, and in the controller's construct check if user is authenticated or no, if authenticated you can propagate the the authenticated user for that session. in my scenario I did need to check if the user is authenticated in the API JsonResource.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('api')->user()) {
            //propagate user in the current session
            $this->middleware('auth:api', [
                'only' => [
                    'index'
                 ]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this example:

```
@if(Auth::user())
   echo "authincatesd user";
@else
   echo "unauthorised";
 @endif
```

Comment: I get `null` returned for Auth::user() even though I'm authenticated.